# Кодировка кириллицы

Tags: android, unicode

Латинские буквы в байты и обратно в символы переводит нормально, а кириллицу не хочет...

Понимаю что дело в кодировке но не понятно как сделать 
artlebedev.ru раскодировал

> ?@825B в привет

7-bit ASCII → KOI8-U + KOI8-R → ISO-8859-5

```
public ToByte(String str)
  {


    byte[] Texttext=new byte[str.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {           
        Texttext[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
    }

    Log.i("MyLogIlnar", new String(bytes)); //Если входное слово Привет то  тут ?@825B   если Hello то Hello
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребята всем спасибо за ответы!

Вот мое решение:

```
           int[] data = new int[str.length()];
           for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
               {
                  data[i] = (int) (str.charAt(i));
                  Log.d("MyLogIlnar", "Байт код " + data[i]);
                  Log.d("MyLogIlnar", "Char (буквы) " + (char) data[i]);  
               }
```

p.s. искать смысла в коде которая находится в шапке не нужно т.к. смысла там нет... это лишь выдержка из кода..Это лишь демонстративный код

Answer (score 3):

Для начала разберёмся что такое `String`. Это объект, который содержит внутри себя:

- указатель на массив символов `char[]`
- начальная позиция в этом массиве, с которой начинается текст (обычно 0)
- длина строки (обычно совпадает с размером массива)

Что же такое массив `char[]`? Это массив Unicode-символов, представленных в кодировке *UTF-16*. Каждый элемент типа char кодирует числовое значение от 0 до 65535 и в подавляющем большинстве случаев соответствует одному символу текста. В очень редких случаях символ кодируется двумя позициями в массиве символов, но сейчас этот вариант можно не рассматривать.

В случае если вы символ приводите к `(byte)` (как в вашем примере), то получается вы просто удаляете половину разрядов его 16-битной кодировки, оставляя только младшие 8 бит. Разумеется, на выходе получается туфта.

У объектов String есть метод `charAt(int)`, который позволяет получить символ `char` с нужной позиции. Есть также конструктор, который принимает на вход готовый массив `char[]` и на основе его содержимого создаёт новую строку.

Что же делать, если нужно закодировать текст в кодировке отличной от UTF-16, или представить в виде массива байт?

Для этого есть класс `Charset`, который как раз и отвечает за кодировки.

Например, вот так:

```
byte[] utf8bytes = "Привет".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

можно получить массив байт в кодировке UTF-8, а вот так:

```
byte[] winbytes = "Привет".getBytes("cp1251");
```

в кодировке Windows.

Собрать обратно строку, из массива байт можно конструктором `new String(byte[], String)`, где первый параметр - массив байт, второй - имя кодировки. Например:

```
String myString = new String(utf8bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Беда в том, что андроид поддерживает далеко не все кодировки, в частности, [документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) обещает поддержку только ISO-8859-1 US-ASCII UTF-16 UTF-16BE UTF-16LE UTF-8

Comment: Да нету у него этой кодировки. Он же сам портит строку.

Comment: @Qwertiy действительно. Не понял вопрос. Поправил ответ.

Comment: А что он вообще пытается сделать? Рикакого смысла в коде не вижу.

Comment: Хороший ответ, обстоятельный)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что не надо было двухбайтовый char стричь до одного байта.

```js
$(function() {
  $("pre").text("привет".replace(/./g, function (ch) {
    return [
      ch,
      ch.charCodeAt(0),
      ch.charCodeAt(0) & 255,
      String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) & 255)
    ].join(" ") + "\n";
  }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Qwertiy это у Вас на JavaScript`е, я не совсем понимаю что и как делать..

     "Привет".getBytes() возвращает тоже ерунду:)  byte[] f =-48,-65,-47,-128,-48,-72  но как не странно если делать new String(f) то получается привет

Comment: @Ilnar, ты берёшь двухбайтовые числа и оставляешь от них один байт, старший при этом теряется. Вот просто не надо так делать и всё. И никакого смысла в функции из вопроса я не вижу. Какой ещё ответ ты ждёшь?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void toByte(String str) {
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(); //В байты
    Log.d("result", Arrays.toString(bytes));
    Log.d("result", new String(bytes)); //Обратно
}
```

Comment: в моем случае в байтах получается так: -48, -65, -47, -128, -48, -72, -48, -78, -48, -75, -47, -126

Comment: @Ilnar это и есть байты в кодировке UTF-8. Что вы ходите получить?